# $\{a,b\}$ are generating set of $\mathbb{Z}$ iff $gcd(a,b)=1$

Tags: group-theory, integers, gcd-and-lcm

Hello a want to prove that
Let $a,b \in  \mathbb{Z}$. The set $\{a,b\}$ are generating set of $\mathbb{Z}$ implies that $gcd(a,b)=1$ \

I know that $gcd(a,b)=1$ iff exist unique $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $1=as+bt$

In other hand $\{a,b\}$ are generating set of $\mathbb{Z}$ means that if $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $z=as+bt$ with $s,t \in \mathbb{Z} $ in particular exist $s_1, t_1$ such that $1=as_1+bt_1$.
This comes down to seeing the uniqueness of $s_1$ and $t_1$. Then i supose that exist other pair $s_2$ and $t_2$ such that $1=as_2+bt_2$ then
\begin{align}
as_1+bt_1=&as_2+bt_2\\
a(s_1-s_2)=&b(t_2-t_1)
\end{align}
but I don't know how to continue.

Thanks

Comment: How about this example: $a=3$, $b=2$ and $1=3-2=3\cdot3-4\cdot2$.

Comment: Firstly, your condition for $gcd(a,b)=1$ is wrong. $gcd(a,b)=1$ does not require unique $s,t$ to the equation $1=as+bt$. In fact, there are always infinite solutions when $gcd(a,b)$. For example, clearly $gcd(3,5)=1$. However, there are infinite solutions to $3s+5t=1$. These solutions could be parametrized as $(2+5x,-1-3x)~\forall x\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: thank you very much I was confused.

Answer (score 2):

Since $gcd(a,b)=1$ we know by bezout's lemma that there exists some pair $s_0,t_0\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$1=as_0+bt_0$$
Hence we can express any integer $k$ as an integer combination of $a$ and $b$ by multiplying both sides of the equation by $k$. We have
$$k=a(s_0k)+b(t_0k)$$
Since $s_0$ and $t_0$ are both integers, so are $s_0k$ and $t_0k$. Hence, we have shown a construction for generating any integer $k$ from the generating set $\{ a,b\}$

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you need to prove uniqueness of $s,t$ to prove your statement. Furthermore, if $gcd(a,b) = 1$ then there are an infinite number of solutions for the equation
\begin{equation}
as + bt = 1
\end{equation}
given by
\begin{equation}
(s,t) \in \left\{ (s_0 + kb , t_0 + ka) : k \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}.
\end{equation}
where $(s_0,t_0)$ is any particular solution of the equation.